# Error in while loop showing

Tags: shell

This script is print the numbers in this manner but showing errors in script but unable to decode the error.

```
   #!/bin/bash
    x=0
     while [ $x -lt 10 ]
      do
       y=$x
       while [ $y -ge 0 ]
       do
            echo "$y \c"
            y=$(($y-1))
      done      #showing done error
       echo      
     x=$(($x+1))
 done          #showing done error
```

Comment: What is the script supposed to do? What does it do?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the syntax - I suspect that this is a line endings issue, typically caused by Windows-style line endings.

Answer (score -1):

Your script is fine, however you should avoid performing such complex treatments with the shell, as they are very slow.

I understand, your script is probably a learning exercise, but for the
future, it is [good habit](http://michipili.github.io/shell/2015/04/12/shell-filter-programming.html) to delegate complex treatments to subprograms, such as filters, and narrow the use of the shell to writing program workflow, assembling specific, complex elements, in a simple way.

Here is my take in AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    for(j = i; j>=0; j--){
      printf("%d%s", j, (j > 0 ? " " : "\n"));
    }
  };
  exit
}'
```

Here instead of AWK, you can use your favourite scripting language, as Python or Perl for instance.